# Typescript refinement confusion

Tags: typescript, union-types

I am reading the book **Programming TypeScript**. I am confused by the **refinement** illustrated by the following example:

```
type UserTextEvent = { value: string; target: HTMLInputElement };
type UserMouseEvent = { value: [number, number]; target: HTMLElement };

type UserEvent = UserTextEvent | UserMouseEvent;

function handle(event: UserEvent) {
  if (typeof event.value === "string") {
    event.value; // string
    event.target; // HTMLInputElement | HTMLElement (1)
    // ...
    return;
  }
  event.value; // [number, number]
  event.target; // HTMLInputElement | HTMLElement (2)
}
```

I think the type of event.target in (1) and (2) should be **HTMLInputElement** and **HTMLElement** respectively. My understanding is that the type of event.target is definite if the type of event.value is definite. But it is **HTMLInputElement | HTMLElement** instead. Can someone explain it more clearly than the book? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking the type of the property unfortunately typescript will not assume the class type because of that. To do that you have to check that yourself with a method that infers the type.

```
type UserTextEvent = { value: string; target: HTMLInputElement };
type UserMouseEvent = { value: [number, number]; target: HTMLElement };

type UserEvent = UserTextEvent | UserMouseEvent;

function isUserTextEvent(event: UserEvent): event is UserTextEvent {
  return typeof event.value === "string";
}

function handle(event: UserEvent) {
  if (isUserTextEvent(event)) {
    event.value; // string
    event.target; // HTMLInputElement  (1)
    // ...
    return;
  }
  event.value; // [number, number]
  event.target; // HTMLElement (2)
}
```

You can check here on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgFQgD2AUQG4QHbBQC8UA3lNgIYA2ArhAFxRzCICWeA5gNxTCWJOEYEwASyALIAZAJJ4wtLNQgBbfIQC%203AFChIsBIgkB7WghzriZCjXpMA2nloqARkgA0UJ66QBdXvyCwmKSUpjKagRQWtq64NDwSBZRJIko6Fi4UQA%20BkgmZhDJwDraAGa0eADGwGzGeFBscGmoGMUAFBBZInmIxQCUTF2WTb2tmZak2lBQiMK0iA16EMZlUMMEAHRUdNBE%201AARCzsXIc6GrEV1bX1UAAWlHgAJsqd3UxpA2TTjWvtTRaGQ6G2A-X6PxmM1B21sEF4AHoEcxWBxOL9od1NoEhCUoEioOJpHIFEpVJYoO0AIz9DH45GbRl0ubABZ4HQzS6Y9Sw3aI5GOZxuRCebzC3y-GE44T8wmhcLkqLtABMtMu2iAA)

when you verify

```
typeof event.value === "string"
```

Typescript can only infer that value is in fact a string and in the else can only be the `[number, number]`

But it cannot infer that `value` is `HTMLInputElement` or `HTMLElement`, so still considers `HTMLInputElement | HTMLElement`. You need to use a method to say that in fact event is `UserTextEvent`

Comment: This is very counter intuitive. I feel the need to summon jcalz LOL

Comment: The type inference system knows that the type of **event.value** is string, why can't it make the decision that the event object is of **UserTextEvent** type? I think that the essence of this question is why the inline expression **typeof event.value === "string"** can not be used as a type guard in this case.